# mysqli_fetch_assoc is sending the first row when I'm using it with an HTML form

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops

I printed a table containing students data and their attendance with HTML/PHP/Mysql and now I'm trying to use a form with radio button to fill the attendance directly. While I'm using the "mysqli_fetch_assoc" function and it's fucntionning normally on everything except the form where it takes the first row only, here's the code  :

```
<?php
require_once("connection.php");
$req="select * from ETUDIANTS";
$rs=mysqli_query($conn,$req) or (die(mysql_error()));
?>

<?php while ($ET=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo($ET['ID_ETUDIANT']) ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo($ET['NOM']) ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo($ET['PRENOM']) ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo($ET['EMAIL']) ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo($ET['DATE_NAISS']) ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo($ET['Prez']) ?> </td> 
                    <?php $cod=($ET['CODE'])?>
                    <td> <form method ="post" action ="attendance.php?code=<?php echo($cod) ?>">
                    <input type="radio" name="Prez" value="1" />Present
                     <input type="radio" name="Prez" value="0" />Absent
                    <input type = "submit" value ="Enregistrer" > 
                </td> 
                </form>  
                    <td><a href ="supprimerEtudiant.php?code=<?php echo($ET['CODE']) ?>">Delete</a> </td> 

            </p>
            <?php  }  ?>
```

The delete URL is fetching the code fine but for the attendance one isn't, here's the attendance.php file :

```
<?php 
require_once("connection.php");
$code=$_GET['code'];
$pres = $_POST['Prez'];
$req = "UPDATE ETUDIANTS SET Prez=$pres  WHERE (CODE=$code)";
mysqli_query($conn,$req) or die ("error frr"); 
header("location:index.php");   

?>
```

(Sorry for the indentation and the mistakes, thanks for the answers !)

Comment: Close the `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by a user that deleted his comment, the solution is : removing the `"?code=<?php echo($cod)>?>` from the form URL and adding a `<input type="hidden" name="code" value="<?php echo($cod) ?>">` and fetching it through `$code=$_POST['code'];`

Thanks for whoever answered !

Comment: A delete process should never be triggered by a hyperlink.

Comment: How would you suggest proceeding ?

Comment: `CREATE`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` processes should all be initiated by a POSTed form.  When you mean to READ (`SELECT`) from a database, you can use $_GET.  Imagine if a robot crawls your site, find the Delete hyperlink, navigates to them all, wipes out your database table.  Think about it.  Also, `echo` is not a function, you can drop the parentheses.  Your code is insecure because you are not using prepared statements.  Your question does not clearly express/isolate the issue.

Comment: In truth, the adjustment described in this answer should not be a solution to the issue.  It is merely a different way to do the same thing.  This question is Unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the advice ! I'm going to fix it and look more about prepared statements and how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Your `</form>` tag is in the wrong place (outside the td that contains it)

Also you are not taking into account the data from your result when printing the radio button, you need to use the `checked` property if applicable

You are also closing a paragraph `</p>` inside the loop for every line and i am not seeing where you are opening it.

also you are NOT closing the table row in the loop

```
<?php while ($ET=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo($ET['ID_ETUDIANT']) ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo($ET['NOM']) ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo($ET['PRENOM']) ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo($ET['EMAIL']) ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo($ET['DATE_NAISS']) ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo($ET['Prez']) ?> </td> 
                    <?php $cod=($ET['CODE'])?>
                    <td> 
                      <form method ="post" action ="attendance.php?code=<?php echo($cod) ?>">
                         <input type="radio" name="Prez" value="1" <?php if ($ET['Prez'] == 1) echo ('checked') ?>/>Present
                         <input type="radio" name="Prez" value="0" <?php if ($ET['Prez'] == 0) echo ('checked') ?> />Absent
                         <input type = "submit" value ="Enregistrer" > 
                      </form>  
                    </td> 
                    <td><a href ="supprimerEtudiant.php?code=<?php echo($ET['CODE']) ?>">Delete</a> </td> 
                </tr>
            <?php  }  ?>
```

you might need to tweak the code a bit to suite your DB values and field names

Comment: I fixed the </form> tag, the </p> one is opened above the code snippet I've copied. I didn't know about the checked property, thanks.